# How to use a button to setText in a TextView and also change screens?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, textview, screen

Im working on an app designed for android 3.0 onwards, and I want to use one button to first setText in a text view and then change screen from screen1 to screen2...

Here is my code so far (causes a crash):

```
    Button mainNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Recipe1);
    mainNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            mTextView.setText("Some Text");

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.bluStudios.Recipes4U.ics", "com.bluStudios.Recipes4U.ics.recipedisplayscreen");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Any ideas???
Thanks in advance :P

EDIT:

Code for 1st screen:

```
public class Recipe_Button_List extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipe_button_list);


    Button mainNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Recipe1);
    mainNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            mTextView.setText("Some Text");
Intent i= new Intent(Recipe_Button_List.this, recipedisplayscreen.class); 
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Code for 2nd screen:

```
public class recipedisplayscreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipedisplayscreen);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    setTitle(R.string.title);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // App icon in action bar clicked; go home
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.recipe_menu1, menu);
        return true;

}
```

}

Comment: what happening when u r running this code?

Comment: Share your error LOG_CAT values for the crash.There may be various reasons for such one

Comment: 03-31 21:43:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(28481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-31 21:43:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(28481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 21:43:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(28481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 21:43:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(28481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-31 21:43:57.702: E/AndroidRuntime(28481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

Comment: simply use `Intent i = new Intent(Activty.this, recipedisplayscreen.class); startActivity(i);` for starting new activity if recipedisplayscreen is in your appliction

Comment: when i use this method i get this error in my editor:No enclosing instance of the type Activity is accessible in scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
    Button mainNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Recipe1);
        mainNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                mTextView.setText("Some Text");
    Intent i= new Intent(YOUR_CURRENT_ACTIVTY_NAME.this, recipedisplayscreen.class); 
///or  you can use Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(),recipedisplayscreen.class); 
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

and must `recipedisplayscreen` activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I added this code to my app.... yet I still get a crash... I think this must be caused by the setText bit, as when I deleted it my app worked fine :/

Comment: not by settext(). post both activity code.then i will tell u?

Comment: u have add this `recipedisplayscreen` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: it is in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: your first Activity code is right and see your second activity after removing action menu.

Comment: I've checked now and i'm certain that there is something wrong with that code which sets the text, as when i delete it my app works fine (switches the screens) as soon as i add:                        final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                mTextView.setText("Some Text");                           I  get a crash

Comment: you have this textView3 in `recipe_button_list` layout?

Comment: ohh!! that's why your app is crashing friend

Comment: put it in `recipe_button_list layout` instead of `recipedisplayscreen`

Comment: haha sorry i didnt tell you :P i feel so stupid now, is there anything i can do????

Comment: put it in recipe_button_list layout instead of recipedisplayscreen

Comment: I can't because the whole point is that when a button with the recipe name is clicked then the app shows the recipedisplayscreen and sets text views with text from strings according to the recipe chosen (method and ingredients)

Comment: ok then add a textview in recipedisplayscreen and  use intent to carry choosen recipe from Recipe_Button_List to recipedisplayscreen  or then display it

Comment: Ok so now I've put TextView1 on Recipe_Button_List and the app is not crashing and is in fact setting the text correctly... any ideas how i can transfer this text to recipedisplayscreen???

Comment: use i.putextra("recipe_name","puri kachodi") and search on google how u recive this value in recipedisplayscreen

Answer (score 1):

```
I think the your main layout do not contain any textView with id (R.id.textView3).

Also the right way is to declare the TextView outside the click listener..
```